# How do you format php error messages? they don't respect css

Tags: php, css

Whenever PHP outputs an error message it disregards css and a beautifully designed page by outputting the message at the top of the page removing anything that stands in its way.

for example

```
some code} else {
echo "error, please do something!";
```

How do I get it to (or ask it nicely) to output the text inside a div that already exists inside my css so that it will obey the formatting and alignment rules that comes with that div.

Comment: In order to be formatted it has to be inside your formatting. It's difficult to tell where you should move this error without more detailed code sample. Please provide a piece of your code with html

Comment: Can you provide more information on what's going on? For instance, in what context is your above code sample running? I think your echo is the problem (see my answer for more detail on that theory), but it's hard to tell without more information.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was running a nested if statement to validate a form, and then outputting an error through echo if invalid. I also had other pages outputting html. The problem was echo as you kindly pointed out and explained as to why this was happening. Your answer and Mario's was very insightful and did alot more than just answer my question. Thank you both. It behaves now! and I understand php better.

Comment: I don't know about **asking it nicely** I think it depends on the personality of your web server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**

Actually, I just realized the "error" you're talking about involves an echo/print out. Here's the problem.

You're `print`ing (`echo`ing) the string error DIRECTLY TO the output buffer (which sends the HTML to the browser when you're finished running all your code). `echo()` and `print()` sends what you are echoing/printing straight out, unless it's in an `output_buffer` block (I won't confuse you with details on that).

So, you're managing your regular html/text output in such a way as to NOT `print` the page content out to the output buffer, but in this case you are using an `echo`, which sends the string data directly to the buffer AT THAT MOMENT.

For instance:

*Your problem in a simple example*

```
<?php

$mystr = "<html>";
$mystr .= "<body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>";

echo "<head></head>";

echo $mystr;

?>
```

Which would give me on output to the browser:

```
<head></head><html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>
```

I am storing the string data, but `echo`ing the HEAD block before I `echo` the other html data.

What I need to do instead:

```
<?php

$mystr = "<html>";
$mystr .= "<head></head>";
$mystr .= "<body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>";

echo $mystr;

?>
```

Which would give me on output to the browser:

```
<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>
```

I am storing the string output (your error, in this case) until I need to output it later. This is what you need to know, and accomplish in your code.

---

I would investigate `error_reporting(0)`/`display_errors`, `error_get_last`, and `set_error_handler`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

So that you could stop sending all errors immediately to the output buffer (which is why it's at the top of the page), and then capture, store and present your errors.

```
error_reporting(0);

set_error_handler('phpLogError');

function phpLogError() {
    $error = error_get_last();

    if ($error['type'] == 1) {
        //do your stuff    
    } 
}

function phpGetLoggedErrors() {
    // return your prettified html errors
}
```

Or, in other words...

**php_error_handle.php**

```
<?php

$GLOBAL['_logged_php_errors'] = array();

error_reporting(0);

set_error_handler('phpLogError');

function phpLogError() {
    global $_logged_php_errors;

    $error = error_get_last();

    if ($error['type'] == 1) {
        $_logged_php_errors[] = "<span>$error</span>";
    } 
}

function phpGetLoggedErrors() {
    global $_logged_php_errors;

    return "<ol><li>".implode('</li><li>',$_logged_php_errors)."</li></ol>";
}

?>
```

**other.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'php_error_handle.php';

// other stuff, pages included/required, etc...
```

Just make sure this require_once happens at the first line of code.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [following `php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) settings:

```
error_prepend_string = "<div class='error'>"
error_append_string = "</div>"
```

Or something to that effect.

Comment: I reread his question and he is in fact demonstrating an echo-related problem, not an error reporting problem.

Comment: @Jared: Well, I don't know. Maybe OP reports back and clears it up. I've read it literally and assumed it was about PHP-generated errors. But regardless, echoing out errors is not best practice. At the very least he should use a `trigger_error("oh noes, something went wrong");` roundtrip, and maybe then use an errormsg spooler like in your example. (Problem might also be that errors are printed out before <body> begin.)

Comment: I know it's confusing. I ended up answering them both, and I don't think either is a very specific answer (considering he mentions sending the error to a div he has on his page). Would be nice to get more detail.

Comment: A little issue though with using this. If the error appears inside the attribute of an html tag then this will break the layout if the attribute is set using single quotes. If you exclusively use single quotes then in this error class use double and vice verse. But if your code contains a mixture of both like mine use no quotes. The latest versions of FF, Chrome and IE8 and up all compensates for missing quotes and display just fine. So use `'<div class=error>'`.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect. I used it like so: ini_set('error_prepend_string',"<div class='error'>")  ;
ini_set('error_append_string',"</div>")  ;
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 2):

Extending @mario above, I've used this at the top of my php file (in dev, not production of course!) which works great. Even in Wordpress admin files!

```
ini_set('error_prepend_string',"<div class='error'>")  ;
ini_set('error_append_string',"</div>")  ;
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try...catch
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

You can make the error echo in your own css.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<div class="yourerrorclass">error, please do something!</div>';
```

If it is in the wrong place in the output, that is because you output the error too soon. The entire HTML is outputted sequentially by PHP. If you output the error before any of the other HTML, the error will be on the top of the page and will actually make your HTML invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying errors to screen should be entirely suppressed when running in production, instead log them to file for checking, and fixing. There are details, and the suggested settings in the php.ini file.